# RecyclerView not completly scrolling to end / imageview width/ height set dynamically in viewholder

Tags: scroll, android-recyclerview

in my RecyclerView (some kind of chat app) i want to scroll to end of view automatically when creating view / adapter is updated. this has been achieved by

```
lva.addItem(message, files);
lva.notifyItemInserted(lva.messageData.size() -1);
lv_msg.scrollToPosition(lva.messageData.size() - 1);
```

for update in example and has perfectly worked yet. But now i´m setting the ImageView (for photos) in item dynamically in ViewHolder like that:

```
  Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(filepath)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .override(400, 400)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(400, 400) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bmdraw, GlideAnimation anim) {


                            holderout.iv_image.getLayoutParams().width = bmdraw.getWidth();
                            holderout.iv_image.getLayoutParams().height = bmdraw.getHeight();
                            holderout.iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmdraw);


                        }
                    });
```

Now view does not scroll completly to end (when there are one or more images in visible part / end of view. it seems it is scrolling to end before views are completly rendered and then after rendering the height of view increases, so that in this moment we are not quite at end / botton of view.

Any idea how to handle that? Is there a chance / event that can be used after views are completly rendered?

thanks

Comment: Nobody any idea?